# Datagridview Cell Index is changing or is incorrect VB.net

Tags: vb.net, indexing, datagridview, datagridviewbuttoncolumn

I have a datagridview that populates with two datagridviewbuttoncolumns(column 0 & 1) when the form loads. The datagridview is on a tab control.The tab with the datagridview is not the first tab to be shown.  I need to be able to reference the cells in the datagridview and I am using datagridview1.Rows(1).Cells(2).Value.

For testing purposes, I have created a button that fires a message box with cell 2, 3, and 4's value.  When the form first loads, I can click the button and I get the correct value for what is in cell 2,3 and 4 with no issue (Correct Values: 'Boy', '27', 'January').  When I go to the tab with the datagridview and try to click the test button again, it appears that all the cell indexes are shifting to the right by 2 (New-Incorrect Values: '', '', 'Boy' or NOTHING, NOTHING, 'Boy').  I am not changing anything with the code, it only happens once I go to the tab with the datagridview.  Its is almost like the buttoncolumns are messing it up.

Does anyone have and ideas or direction to workaround this?

Comment: Did you add the DGV columns in the designer as well as in your code?  Did you set the DGV.DataSource property?

Comment: No.  I add them all in through the code as I load the gridview.